# Jsoup não retornando nenhum valor

Tags: java, maven, jsoup

Estou com um problema com blibioteca Jsoup, que quando eu tento fazer a conexão com uma certa página, ele simplesmente não me retorna nenhum valor a partir da conexão.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://pt.stackoverflow.com/").get();

        //Pegando elemento das perguntas
        Elements elements = doc.select("a.question-hyperlink");

        System.out.println("O  titulo da página é: "+doc.title());

        //exibindo titulo da pergunta
        for(int i = 0; i <elements.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(elements.get(i).text());
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Erro "+ e);
    }
}
```

Por coincidência eu testei com Stack Overflow e ele deu o mesmo problema.

Retorno do IDE Netbeans:

```
Erro: org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403, URL=http://pt.stackoverflow.com/

------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.282s
Finished at: Sun May 15 13:26:41 BRT 2016
Final Memory: 5M/109M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Não sei se isso influência em algo, mas o tipo de projeto é Maven.

@EDIT

Consegui resolver o problema, adicionando o seguinte método na conexão.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://pt.stackoverflow.com/")
                .userAgent("Mozilla").get();
```

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 0):

**Observação Importante:** Ao acessar qualquer página ou serviço usando um Web Crawler é importante verificar antes se o fornecedor permite a leitura do conteúdo desta forma. Em alguns casos em é permitido, o próprio fornecedor disponibiliza uma `API` para que este acesso seja feito de forma correta.

---

O código `403` de status `HTTP` é referente ao erro `Forbidden` (Proibido). Isso acontece por vários motivos, mas o mais recorrente é o que a página percebeu que o acesso não está sendo feito por um navegador.
Nestes casos basta usar o método [`Connection#userAgent`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#userAgent-java.lang.String-) para defini-lo de acordo com um navegador aceito pelo servidor. O do `Chrome 55` no `Windows 8 - 64 bits`, por exemplo:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
```

Adicionando entre a chamada do [`Jsoup#connect`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#connect-java.lang.String-) e do [`Connection#get`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#get--) da seguinte forma:

```
...
.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36")
...
```